# Spring Data Jpa sorting query for complex attributes of an object

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

In my Employee object I have Address object and address has String zipCode and streetNo. Now I need to sort Employee object on zipCode.

I am trying to write:

```
List<Employee> findAllOrderByAddressZipCodeDesc();
```

But I am getting:

> no property zip code found for Employee.

How can I dynamically pass the sorting column name(zipCode or streetNo)?

How to sort on zipCode?

Answer (score 0):

there is a @Query attribute that You can add to your interface methods.
Here it is the link

https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions

Here it is an example with spring data mongo

```
 @Component
  public interface ItemBookedRepository extends MongoRepository<ItemBooked, String> {

 @Query(value = "{'endDate':{ $gte : ?0 },'startDate':{ $lte : ?1 } }")
  List<ItemBooked> findInRange(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate);

  List<ItemBooked> findByItem(Item item);

 }
```